# jQuery clicking an element, Child interferes

Tags: jquery, events, handler

I have an even in jQuery, when they click the DIV it hides itself. My problem is that the SPAN it interfering with it, meaning I have to click outside of the span and exactly on the DIV.

Can I make it so when they click the DIV or any child element of that, it will do the event? I thought it would be something like $('.item', this) or something..

```
<div class="item">
  <span>Testing</span>
</div>

$('.item').live('click', function(e) {
  $(e.target).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of hiding the target of the event, which could be anything inside the div, hide `this` div:

```
$('.item').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```